# metricSystem parameter support in "discover/search"

Tags: here-api

distance is given in meters for this query:
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=my-app-id&app_code=my-app-code&at=36.97425,-122.03099&pretty

Is there any plan to support "metricSystem" parameter(as is done in the case of Routing APIs) so that the result can provide distance in miles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, the distances are just given back in meters from the Places API. There are no further plans to change this in future. But you can easily calculate the values into miles on client side.

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be calculated & will do that:). However the query was to know whether there is plan to support it similar to how its done in Routing APIs so that client code can be kept uniform. Thanks though for the clarification.

Comment: No, this is not planned.